# Black (and sometimes blue) screen after Windows 7 login

Tags: windows-7, login, visual-artifacts

I have a new PC with Windows 7. At login to my user (not admin) account, there is always a "black screen" moment - the login screen dims, then my desktop appears and with it, for a split second, a Windows command prompt window top-left.

About a month ago, the screen not only dimmed, it went black and stayed black. No trace of the mouse, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> got no response. The only solution was to unplug the PC and start again. On reboot, Windows suggests starting in safe mode.

Lately I've been getting this problem practically every day, except now the screen goes blue and sometimes blue-green. On reboot, fortunately, the login has always, at least so far, been successful. I've followed Microsoft's advise about reinstalling the video driver and checking some registry key.

== deleted useless bits 23 march 2014 ===

**!! If you came here with the same problem** - no need to read on. Even with Catalyst disabled the problem returned. But I tried the following and so far haven't had a black/blue/white screen -- avoid log-on, and avoid using your PC after log-on, until all disc activity has stopped. I hardly ever shut down at all now, just log-on.

Comment: How about Disk checks? RAM checks? Event Log entries?  Testing as a different user?  What "Registry key" did you check, and why?

Comment: Try swapping out the monitor, preferably one that has a different connector (if you are using VGA now, switch to DVI, or vice-versa).

Comment: Checking the registry key was suggested on the Microsoft website (regoogling can't find it), but the key was OK so that wasn't the problem. Will try swapping monitors. Thanks.

Comment: Monitor now connected with DVI. No black screen but too early to say if it's the solution. Hope so.

Answer (score 0):

After 10 days with no repetition of the problem, which was repeating itself almost daily, it looks like the solution was indeed disabling ATI's Catalyst Control Center.

Use msconfig -> startup tab and deselect Catalyst Control Center

Comment: I'm ashamed to say the problem has returned. Black screen after log-on. Nothing in the event logs point to anything as the cause. However, it doesn't seem to happen if, before logging on and after logging on, you wait until Windows has ceased all activity (no flashing disk or CPU lights).